# Помогите с mysql запросом

Tags: php, select, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, не могу сообразить.

У меня в mysql таблицы есть поля, например category, region
в них предполагается указание нескольких значений через ",", например в поле category - "1,5,7,45"

Как мне составить запрос select чтобы вывести данную строку имея значение запроса category например - "5" . Идея с like не очень подходит.

Comment: нормализуйте вашу базу данных. Хранение нескольких значений в одном поле  - очень плохая идея. Отсюда появляются проблемы вроде вашей. Заведите таблицу-связку, и при выборке делайте джойн с предыдущей таблицей

Comment: Я тоже за перестроение базы! Вы в конце концов запутаетесь с таким подходом.

Comment: тут как вариант нашел функцию FIND_IN_SET, что скажите? По поводу медленности ее работы информации не нашел. Сейчас буду экспериментировать

Comment: @15828, про нормализацию базы вам уж написали. Не городите костылей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Присоединяюсь к тем кто советует нормализировать базу, почитать про нормализацию и нормальные формы можно например в [русской википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). То-что описали вы это неправильный способ использования реляционной базы данных.

<strike>*Добавлю так-же что для больших и нагруженных баз данных лучше отказаться от использования join-ов (в пользу вложенных select-ов например), это довольно-таки дорогая операция. Впрочем не уверен, возможно серьёзные проблемы она доставит только на действительно больших таблицах. Тут я не специалист.*</strike>

Видимо был неправ. Судя по всему вложенные селекты в mysql работают чещё хуже чем `JOIN`.

Comment: > Добавлю так-же что для больших и нагруженных баз данных лучше отказаться от использования join-ов (в пользу вложенных select-ов например), это довольно-таки дорогая операция

Тут, наверное, единственным критерием выбора будет все-таки explain. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577224

Comment: >лучше отказаться от использования join-ов (в пользу вложенных select-ов например)

крайне спорное утверждение. Чем-то можете это подтвердить (разумеется, кроме фразы "я так думаю")?

Comment: Спорить не стану, ибо не специалист. В любом случае высшая инстанция это explain. Но всё-же мне кажется что join, вынужденный ворочать обе таблицы целиком должен-быть медленнее двух простых селектов. Возможно я просто не увидел существующего способа оптимизировать join, сделав его запредельно дешёвым. В таком случае каюсь и прошу кинуть в меня ссылкой на этот способ.

Comment: @MrClon, я тоже не специалист, но думаю, что джойны уже давно целиком не берут таблицы. Если в where стоит `table1.id = 1`, то можно его проанализировать заранее и взять только одну запись из первой таблицы. Если же в where/on ничего не стоит, то это означает, что нужен полный джойн, от которого никуда не деться. Ну и с совсем наивной точки зрения на подзапросы должно уходить больше транзакционных издержек (O(n) против O(1) у джойна).

Comment: Посмотрел EXPLAIN, и теперь я ничего не понимаю.
LEFT JOIN и вложенный запрос делают две выборки. Но в случае с вложенным запросом выборка по целевой таблице (той в которой лежат сами записи) происходит без индекса и соответственно перелопачивает всю таблицу. Если воспроизвести оба запроса вручную (получить список ID записей в нужной категории, и запросить посты ID которых входит в список) то получается два простых (SIMPLE) выборки по индексу, всё кошерно. Похоже на какие-то странности оптимизатора.

Прикладываю пасту с EXPLAIN всех четырёх запросов http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iFHJE1WE

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category REGEXP "^5[^0-9]*|,5[^0-9]|,5$";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: в таком случае будет цеплять значения содержащие 5 (45, 25, 135 51 .. etc) .(точка) - любой символ. Держать в поле несколько значений удобно только если данные выбираются, а не являются условием для выборки.

Comment: "5" не пройдет  
"352" пройдет

Comment: «У меня была проблема, я использовал регэкспы что-бы решить её, теперь у меня две проблемы» (:

Но даже забыв про регэкспы, зачем учить людей плохому?